# find unused pictures in dreamweaver

Tags: web, dreamweaver

Good morning. I ask you some help... Is there a way in Dreamweaver CC to find unused pictures/images? I'm working in a website, but also i've too much photos that I'd to organize in a better way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the top menu, select Site -> Site Options -> Check Links Sitewide, or press Ctrl+F8 or Cmd+F8.  This will list a variety of information for you, including pictures that are not used anywhere (under Orphaned Files).

This information is from Dreamweaver CC (2019) but present in earlier versions, too.